Middle name not showing in PDF print
I've got several orders with customers having a middle name.
I want to include these in the PDF prints, but somehow it won't show.
This is my current PDF address template:
{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}|{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}}, {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}|{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}CIF/NIF: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|

And this is the corresponding address from table sales_order_address

It clearly shows the middlename, but it won't get visible on the Magento PDF prints.
I've also enabled the Show Middle Name (initial) setting, didn't help either.
Also removed the depend around middlename (so always show middlename), didn't help either.
The PDF print

If I make any changes in this address (through admin or db) in any other fields (company, name etc) it does take affect, but the middlename won't ever show.

Go to System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options -> Show Middle Name (initial) and set value to Yes

I've already tried that (as mentioned in the OP), but that didn't made any difference unfortunately.

Maybe a plugin is used to hide the middle name?
